# append rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
testy = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=True, index_col='Date', dayfirst=True)
# testy's shape is (6, 4), so 6 rows and 4 columns
basey = testy.mean(0)
# basey is the average of each column of testy, and the shape is (1, 4)
```

I would like to get errory of each row in testY, I did this:

```
errory = testy - basey.T
```

However, as testy is (6, 4) and basey.T is (1, 4), seems I am not getting the right result. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: as they are not the same shape would seem to me you'll need to iterate over testy rows?

Comment: Always nice if you provide a copy + paste example of the important data (so testy in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Often mathematical operations are easier done in `numpy`. You can extract dataframes numpy arrays with `df.values`. So in this case, if your frame has the correct dimensions you can do:

```
error_y = test_y.values - base_y.T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dataframe to numpy array, do the operations(which are relatively easily performed in numpy) and then convert back.

```
testy =  pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=True, index_col='Date', dayfirst=True)
# Get the numpy array for testy, less the indices
arr = testy.reset_index().values[:, 1:]
mean = np.mean(arr, axis = 0)
# Convert back to pandas, set the indices from testy
errory = pd.DataFrame(arr - mean, index = testy.index.values)
# Set the column names in errory same as testy
errory.columns = testy.columns
```